# error on npm start command in angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, macos

I am completely new to angular js and I have started learning through [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) tutorial. While running the development web server using `npm start` I get the below error :

```
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart /path_to/angular-phonecat
> npm install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /path_to/angular-phonecat
> bower install


> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start /path_to/angular-phonecat
> http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1238:14)
    at listen (net.js:1274:10)
    at net.js:1383:9
    at doNTCallback3 (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:358:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:469:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3

npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start script 'http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /pathto/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
```

I have also tried changing the address and port but still the same error.
Can someone help?

PS : I am using Osx.

Answer (score 0):

go to the command line and do

```
ps aux | grep 8000
```

and get PID number, should be the second column i believe, like a 5 digit number, ,then;

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

try npm start again.

I advice learning angular2 instead. As it wont be of much benefit for you learning angular 1 now.

Answer (score 0):

**EADDRINUSE** -- this means the port which this server is trying to use is already in use by some other process so first kill it and then run your server again.